# Entity Framework casting issue

Tags: entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework issue. I have this code, where MyType2 derives from MyType1:

```
var EF = AppDbContext.Current;
var result = EF.Set<MyType1>().Where(
  x => x.Type == "MyType2" &&
  EF.Set<MyType2>().Any(y => y.Code == ((MyType2)x).Code)
);
```

When I run it, it throws this 'NotSupportedException':
Unable to cast the type 'MyType1' to type 'MyType2'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

How can I properly cast MyType1 to MyType2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every MyType1 is a type MyType2, however, every MyType2 is a type of MyType1. That is why you cannot (and should not) convert MyType1 instance to MyType2.

You can use `.OfType<>` in this case, this is an example, and not sure will work 100% for you, but may give an idea:

```
var mytype2Instances = dbcontext.MyType1.OfType<MyType2>().List();
```

Comment: So there is no way I can read the Code property from x? (In this case I now that x is type of MyTípe2).

Comment: @gkatai please see the update, hope it helps!

Comment: Downcasting is perfectly valid in c#. His problem stems from L2E Expressions.